# Spring-Boot and MySql unable to connect

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, spring-boot

I am trying to connect to mysql database, but it's not working. I took a course from udemy and followed all steps, but i am getting always the same error, then I followed the steps from [this](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest) and [this](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) guides, but doesn't work.

Things i tried so far:

- new IDE
- clean & rebuild project
- deleting property `spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` from `application.properties`
- tried to add Mysql Connector manually

I've ran out of ideas.
 Need some assistance

**Update:** **Stacktrace**

```
2017-03-12 19:20:53.388  INFO 7808 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2017-03-12 19:20:53.515  INFO 7808 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
2017-03-12 19:20:54.046  WARN 7808 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2017-03-12 19:20:54.061  INFO 7808 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-03-12 19:20:54.106  INFO 7808 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-03-12 19:20:54.130 ERROR 7808 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:1.4.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:1.4.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372) [spring-boot-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:1.4.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-1.4.5.RELEASE.jar:1.4.5.RELEASE]
```

[Packages in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FJew.png) 

[Application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txwIe.png)

*POM.XML*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stopCozi</groupId>
    <artifactId>stopCozi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>StopCozi</name>
    <description>Stop Cozi </description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for HTML -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependecy for database -->


        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**User Entity**

```
@Entity 
public class User {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String password;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String userId;
    private String email;
    private String phoneNo;
    private String PIN;
    private List<Appointment> appointmentList;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    //getter and setter
```

**UserDaoRepository**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "user", path = "user")
public interface UserDaoRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

    User findByName(@Param("name") String name);
    User findByEmail(@Param("email") String email);

}
```

Comment: Is it all the exception stacktrace ? I don't see the root cause.

Comment: Update with the new error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your maven project file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Your application.properties file is just telling spring what jpa provider to use.  You still have to include the jdbc provider implementation files.

Comment: Help me to get rid of that error, thanks :) Any clue why I am getting the new error?  Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory. (I will start searching for answers)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the ORM association for this field :

```
private List<Appointment> appointmentList;
```

For example if a `User` may have multiple `Appointment` and an `Appointment` may be related to zero or one `User`, you could define the `Appointment` relationship in this way in the `User` entity  :

```
@Entity      
public class User{
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
  private List<Appointment> appointmentList;
}
```

And in the Appointment entity you could define this relationship :

```
@Entity      
public class Appointment{
  ...
  @ManyToOne
  private User user;
 ...
 }
```

If you encounter other mapping errors, I advise you to understand the Hibernate/JPA basics.

Here is the actual documentation of Hibernate (v 5): http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html

Here is the documentation part on the relationships definition between entities :

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations